# Determine any local and global extreme values ​for f

Tags: calculus, functions

Find local and global extreme values for f.

$$
f(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{split}
\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x} &, x > 0 \\
\frac{x}{2}+1 &, x \leq 0
\end{split}
\right.
$$

I know I need to get the derivative. But what is the next move?
The derivative:
-e^-x/x - (e^-x-1)/x^2

Comment: So did you calculate the derivative? What result did you get?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write it. -e^-x/x - (e^-x-1)/x^2 @MattiP.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, yes, you need to take the derivative of f and set it to zero. After that you can determent the value of x that satisfies this expression. If you plug the x value into your original function f, you will get the minimum/maximum value of your function.

Comment: Hey, just found out that x=0, how do i know what is min and max?

Comment: with the second derivative of your function at the point x = 0. If f''(0)<0 then it is the maximum value. If f''(0)>0 then it is the minimum value.